# HAProxy use urls in server config?

Tags: haproxy

Right now, my config looks like this:

```
server node1 10.20.x.y:80 check
server node2 10.20.x.y:80 check
server node3 10.20.x.y:80 check
```

What would be the best way to use URLS here instead of IPs?

Something like (But this does not seem to work):

```
server node1 url-1.google.com:80 check
server node2 url-2.google.com:80 check
server node3 url-3.google.com:80 check
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I may have posted this question on the wrong site.

I have posted this question on [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/910272/haproxy-use-urls-in-server-config/910273#910273) aswell and received the following answer:

> When you want to use DNS resolution you will need to specify a
>   [*"resolvers"*](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.9/configuration.html#5.3.2) section where you configure DNS.

Which worked for me.